# Create Transform to part of mesh in Unity?

Tags: transform, unity-game-engine, mesh, fbx

I'm working on a project in unity and there's a script that has a reference to a transform to a character's hand. This is used to put an item in the character's hand and have it follow it as the hand moves. When I double click on the transform I don't get a reference to any prefab though, but it does have the data of the mesh at that location. How do I create a transform like this?

Thanks!

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish: [image]

Comment: I suspect I can answer this question, but I don't fully understand what you want. You're asking how to achieve something you already have a script for... What EXACTLY do you want?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to do what is shown, but I can't get another transform to part of a mesh.  I didn't write/do what you see in the screenshot, another programmer did that isn't here anymore.

Comment: I've tried to answer your question to the best of my understanding. What exactly does it show for "the data of the mesh"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hand is a "bone" in the models skeleton. A model's skeleton in Unity is represented by a tree of GameObjects with Transform components.

To create a Transform like that you would have to import a model with a skeleton. To add it to the field in the inspector you would have to locate it in the Project window and drag it into the inspector field.